# Buildroot date is wrong

Tags: raspberry-pi, date, buildroot

When I flash a buildroot image for the raspberrypi3, using the date command will give me 1970-01-01. I have to manually reset that every time.

What would be the correct way to handle this?

Should I make a post-build script to change the date ahead of the image flash?

Answer (score 0):

Install a Real Time Clock in your HW, or use NTP.